# Ruby - how to add items from ActiveRecord to an existing hash structure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am updating an existing Rails project and the menu of the project is rendered through the following structure:

```
def main_menu
    {
        users: item_hash('Users', @view.users_path),
        cars: item_hash('Cars', @view.cars_path),
        bikes: item_hash('Bikes', @view.bikes_path),
        other_group: item_group('Other', {
          fees: item_hash('Fees', @view.fees_path),
          penalties: item_hash('Penalties', @view.penalties_path),
          bonuses: item_hash('Bonuses', @view.bonuses_path)
        }),
        calendar: calendar_menu
    }
end
```

I need to add a new item to this structure (data would be loaded from DB) and the desired output would look like this (added `brands_group`):

```
def main_menu
        {
            users: item_hash('Users', @view.users_path),
            brands_group: item_group('Brands', {
              Audi: item_hash('Audi', @view.edit_brand_path(1),
              BMW: item_hash('BMW', @view.edit_brand_path(2),
              Toyota: item_hash('Toyota', @view.edit_brand_path(3)
            }),
            cars: item_hash('Cars', @view.cars_path),
            bikes: item_hash('Bikes', @view.bikes_path),
            other_group: item_group('Other', {
              fees: item_hash('Fees', @view.fees_path),
              penalties: item_hash('Penalties', @view.penalties_path),
              bonuses: item_hash('Bonuses', @view.bonuses_path)
            }),
            calendar: calendar_menu
        }
    end
```

However, how do I load the data from the `Brand` model and put them to such a structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
brands = Brand.all.map do |brand|
  [brand.name.to_sym, item_hash(brand.name, @view.edit_brand_path(brand.id))]
end.to_h #assuming you have a name column on the brands table

{
  users: item_hash('Users', @view.users_path),
  brands_group: item_group('Brands', brands),
  cars: item_hash('Cars', @view.cars_path),
  bikes: item_hash('Bikes', @view.bikes_path),
  other_group: item_group('Other', {
    fees: item_hash('Fees', @view.fees_path),
    penalties: item_hash('Penalties', @view.penalties_path),
    bonuses: item_hash('Bonuses', @view.bonuses_path)
  }),
  calendar: calendar_menu
}
```